# How to read just heading when filename is defined as a string string datatype

Tags: python, csv, class, init, read.csv

I have to work with

```
def __init__(self, filepath: str) -> None:
```

which seems to mean if I want to assign just the header of the CSV file to a variable

```
with open(filepath) as Doc:
    DocH = csv.reader(Doc[0])
```

I get this error

Class 'TextIO' does not define '_*getitem*_', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances

And I have to separate the heading from the data

Below is the whole code:

```
def __init__(self, filepath: str) -> None:
    try:
        with open(filepath) as Doc:
            DocH = csv.reader(Doc[0])

            DocD = csv.reader(Doc)
```

Comment: Why do you think `Doc[0]` would do anything other than raise an error? In any case, the error is telling you precisely why you cannot do that.

Comment: the usual way to open a file is like this: `with open(filepath) as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)`